# how to select today date in a file with cat and grep?

Tags: linux, grep, cat

How can I select todays log from:

```
Oct  9 21:47:06 server dovecot[1513]: imap(yar99@vmail.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=235 out=760
Oct  9 21:47:06 server dovecot[1513]: auth-worker(28110): shadow(yar99@vmail.com,127.0.0.1): unknown user
Oct  9 21:47:06 server dovecot[1513]: auth-worker(28110): shadow(yar99@vmail.com,127.0.0.1): unknown user
Oct  9 21:47:06 server dovecot[1513]: imap-login: Login: user=<yar99@vmail.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1850, secured, session=<ImGl4XUEHAB/AAAB>
Oct  8 21:47:06 server dovecot[1513]: imap(yar99@vmail.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=162 out=7805
Oct  8 21:47:08 server dovecot[1513]: auth-worker(28110): shadow(elnaz75@vmail.com,144.76.43.87): unknown user
Oct  8 21:47:08 server dovecot[1513]: auth-worker(28110): shadow(elnaz75@vmail.com,144.76.43.87): unknown user
Oct  7 21:47:08 server dovecot[1513]: imap-login: Login: user=<elnaz75@vmail.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=144.76.43.87, lip=144.76.43.87, mpid=1853, secured, session=<gkTD4XUE0QCQTCtX>
Oct  6 21:47:08 server dovecot[1513]: imap(elnaz75@vmail.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=235 out=765
Oct  4 21:47:09 server dovecot[1513]: auth-worker(28110): shadow(maryam36@vmail.com,127.0.0.1): unknown user
Oct  4 21:47:09 server dovecot[1513]: auth-worker(28110): shadow(maryam36@vmail.com,127.0.0.1): unknown user
Oct  4 21:47:09 server dovecot[1513]: imap-login: Login: user=<maryam36@vmail.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1856, secured, session=<sb/G4XUEIAB/AAAB>
```

My command is:

```
cat /var/log/maillog | grep imap-login:\ Login | sed -e 's/.*Login: user=<\(.*\)>, method=.*/\1/g' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `grep` twice in a pipeline with `sed` since it can do the selection, too:

```
sed -n "/^$(date '+%b %_d').*imap-login: Login/s/.*Login: user=<\(.*\)>, method=.*/\1/p" /var/log/maillog | sort -u
```

I also eliminated the separate call to `uniq` since `sort -u` takes care of that.

I used guido's `date` command to select the current date, but I replaced the deprecated backticks with `$()`, as Mark did, which is specified by POSIX and supported by all modern Bourne-derived shells.

Here is a version of Mark Setchell's AWK answer which sorts and uniques the result.

```
awk -F"[ <>=,]*" -v d="^$(date '+%b %_d')" '$0 ~ d && /imap-login/ {a[$9] = $9} END {n = asort(a); for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {print a[i]}}' /var/log/maillog
```

It requires GAWK.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe do something along these lines with `awk`, and treating spaces, angle brackets, commas and equals signs all as alternate field separators:

```
awk -F"[ <>=,]*" -v d="$(date '+%b %_d')" '$0 ~ d && /imap-login/{print $1,$2,$9,$11}' maillog
Oct 9 yar99@vmail.com PLAIN
```